# Query Remote Database from Rails 3.2 Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to query a 3rd party database which is entirely separate from the Rails 3.2 application I'm building (belongs to a different application which my company uses internally).

Ultimately, I'll be setting up a cron to load new rows from the "other" database which my Rails application will be processing.

I have the access to `otherdb` set up, and I'm wondering where to go from here—do I create a new entry in `config/database.yml`?  If so, how do I then specify when a query is to be directed to `otherdb`, instead of my default Rails `development` or `production` db?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to implement this requirement, the easiest of which would be to use `config/database.yml` and custom namespaced model(s).

Setting up something similar to the below, using a suffix of `Rails.env` to follow the naming convention will provide the functionality you outlined.

First, create new entries for the external database each of your existing environments. It'll help you to be able to test the functionality.

```
# database.yml
development:
  # add configuration as required

otherdb_development:
  # add configuration as required
```

Second, add a model for each of the specific tables you need to access in the `otherdb` database. I'd recommend adding a namespace directory for these models (`otherdb` in the example below) to avoid confusion and potential clobbering:

```
# /app/models/otherdb
class Otherdb::Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "otherdb_#{Rails.env}"
  set_table_name "foo" # customize this if the table name will be different from the classname and is required
end
```

You can then use (as an example) methods on `Otherdb::Foo` and use the resulting data as required.

Comment: Thanks--I'll give this a try.  On a related note: my development, test and production databases are all PostgreSQL, so I'm running the 'pg' gem--will I need to *also* install a MySQL-specific gem to deal with the remote MySQL database?  Can these "play nice" together, or should I expect some conflicts?

Comment: You're correct: if the remote database is a different product then it will need to use a different adapter.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem yesterday. Since you are using Rails 3.2, all your models that connect to the external database will have to be subclasses of a single, abstract class that establishes the connection. In earlier versions of Rails, @Sasha's answer would have worked. But in 3.2, that answer will lead you to getting various confusing database errors. (What errors you get depends on what DB you use.)

In Rails 3.2, this is the only way I have found that will work:

1. Make a common base class for all models that need to talk to a
   non-default database.
2. Tell ActiveRecord that this base class is abstract by calling `self.abstract_class = true`.
3. Call `establish_connection` in the base class.

Here is an example with students and courses from an external table:

```
# database.yml:
development:
  # default configuration goes here

other_development:
  # external db configuration goes here

class OtherTable < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection "other_#{Rails.env}"
end

class Student < OtherTable
end

class Course < OtherTable
end
```

If you'd like more detail, see the blog post I wrote titled [Establishing a Connection to a Non-Default Database in Rails 3.2](http://ilikestuffblog.com/2012/09/21/establishing-a-connection-to-a-non-default-database-in-rails-3-2-2/).